# Why do nested random effects work in nlme but not work in lme4?

Tags: r, mixed-models

[A glimse of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCsX8.png)

I want to see the effect of M on Com using linear mixed model, with M as the fixed effect and year nested in plot as random effect. There is no problem if I use lme in package 'nlme'.

```
fit <- lme(Com ~ M + random = ~ 1|plot/year, data)
```

But it didn't work in lmer in package 'lme4'.

```
fit <- lmer(Com ~ M + (1|plot/year), data)

# Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations
```

However, it works if I only include plot or year in the random effect. Is there any way to solve it?

```
fit <- lme(Com ~ M + random = ~ 1|plot, data)
fit <- lme(Com ~ M + random = ~ 1|year, data)
```

Comment: That's not valid `lme` code. The `+` should be a `,`.

Comment: Could be related to your data (an issue with it that `lme()` does not stop for), see Ben Bolker's answer and warning to a (possible) similar issue: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/187838/216174. It is difficult to provide much insight without a reproducible example / more information about the structure of your data.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I want to express that it works if I only include plot or year in the random effect in lmer.
`fit <- lmer(Com ~ M + (1|plot), data) `
`fit <- lmer(Com ~ M + (1|plot), data)`

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The reason it does not work with `lmer` is that your grouping factors have the same number of levels as you have observations. More explicitly `with(data, unique(cbind(plot, year))) < nrow(data)` returns `FALSE`.

Comment: Hi Oliver, you are right! I change my model as `fit <- lmer(Com ~ M+ (1|year)+(1|plot), data = t)` and there is no error, but a warning information`  “boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular”. summary(fit) works.` But I can’t get R2 of the model by using r2 in package ‘sjstats’ and
‘performance’. It returned NA. Do you know why and how can I get R2?

Answer (score 0):

nlme is well known to deal with nested random effects and not with interactions whereas on the contrary lme4 deals well with interactions and does not suits well for some things nlme is good for. I think lme4 provides variance component models only whereas nlme allows correlations between observations. Maybe if your nested structure lies within your data you could try `fit <- lmer(Com ~ M + (1:plot) + (1|year:plot), data = t)`, assuming that years are nested within plots.

Answer (score 0):

`fit <- lmer(Com ~ M + (1:plot) + (1|year:plot), data = t)` and `fit <- lmer(Com ~ M + (1:plot) + (1|plot:year), data = t)` are equivalent but the latter formula may be more consistant. You could also compare the results of this command with `fit <- lme(Com ~ M, random = ~ 1|plot/year, data)` and see if you find the same variance components. I think it should work.